# foldr and foldr1 Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

I am trying to dive deep in the folds, considering it seems a very powerful asset to me. However, can you help me with this:

```
foldr  (/) 2 [1,2,3] -- (1/(2/(3/2))), result 0,75 {where 2 is base)
foldr1 (/)   [2,2,3] -- (1/(2/(3/2))), result 3.00 {where 2 is base)
```

I think I am seriously overseeing an essential difference between the folds. Thx

Comment: Both iterate over over the input, the only difference is that `foldr` will apply the last value with the given value `z` (here `2`), whereas the other `foldr` will not do that.

Comment: Meaning that my deconstruct of foldr1 (1/(2/(3/2))) is wrong, since it does have a value z, but takes the head of the list instead ~

Answer (score 7):

`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` has as implementation:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _ z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

So that means that if we enter `foldr f z [x1, x2, x3]`, then it is evaluated as:

```
   foldr f z [x1, x2, x3]
-> f x1 (foldr f z [x2, x3])
-> f x1 (f x2 (foldr f z [x3]))
-> f x1 (f x2 (f x3 (foldr f z [])))
-> f x1 (f x2 (f x3 z))
```

So for your example that will evaluate to:

```
  (/) 1 ((/) 2 ((/) 3 2))
= 1 / (2 / (3 / 2))
= 1 / (2 / 1.5)
= 1 / 1.33333...
= 0.75
```

The `foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a` function is *almost* similar, except that in case we see the a 1-element list, we return that element, so the difference is:

```
foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
foldr1 _ [x] = x
foldr f (x:xs) = f x (foldr1 f xs)
```

So that means that for a `foldr1 f [x1, x2, x3]` we get:

```
   foldr1 f [x1, x2, x3]
-> f x1 (foldr1 f [x2, x3])
-> f x1 (f x2 (foldr1 f [x3]))
-> f x1 (f x2 x3))
```

So for the sample input, we get:

```
  (/) 2 ((/) 2 3)
= 2 / (2 / 3)
= 2 / 0.6666...
= 3.0
```

So in case `z` and `xi` have the same type, then `foldr f z [x1, ..., xn]` is equal to `foldr1 f [x1, ..., xn, z]`.

Answer (score 6):

In general

```
foldr1 op [y1, ..., yn, x]
```

is essentially the same as

```
foldr op x [y1, ..., yn]
```

as long as `n >= 1`. That is, in your special case

```
foldr1 (/) [2, 2, 3]
```

will evaluate to `2/(2/3) = 3`.

With the division operator, it's a bit boring, because

```
foldr1 (/) [y, y, x1, ... , xn]
  = y/(y/(foldr1 (/) [x1, ..., xn]))
  = foldr1 (/) [x1, ..., xn]
```

for all `n >= 1`. So, in your example, it should just return the result of

```
foldr1 (/) [3]
```

which is of course `3.0`, and it does indeed evaluate to `3.0`.

Here is less degenerate example:

```
foldr1 (/) [2, 3, 5, 7] --  evals to 0.47619047619047616
```

Here, it gives the same result as `2 / (3 / (5 / 7))`, which is in turn
the same as

```
foldr (/) 7 [2, 3, 5]
```

I hope it clarifies the order of evaluation a little bit.