# foldr and foldl function applied on div function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am really confused on how foldr and foldl works. Like for example using like this on the list [1,2,3]

```
foldr (+) 0 => 1 : (2 :(3:([])) 
             => 1 + (2 +(3+0)) = 6
```

And this makes sense because each : is replaced  by the + sign and the empty set by 0.

But when I type the following two lines in the ghci I get:

```
foldr div 7 [13,6,19]   -- gives me 4 
foldl div 7 [13,6,19]   -- gives me 0
```

I thought I would get a list in which each element was divided by 7 but instead I just get one element. 
Can someone please walk me through how the ghci calculates this.

Comment: No, if you want to `div` every element, you need ``map (`div` 7) [13, 6, 19]``

Comment: `foldr div 7 [13, 6, 19]` means you calculate `div 13 (div 6 (div 19 7)) == div 13 (div 6 2) == div 13 3 == 4`, for `foldl` it is the opposite: `div (div (div 7 13) 6) 19 == div (div 0 6) 19 == div 0 19 == 0`.

Comment: Also, `div` is integer division, so it rounds down (you can get the remainder with `rem`). Your `foldl` example rounds 7/13 down to 0 and then 0/6 and 0/19 are zero.  Your `foldr` example rounds 19/7 to 2, then 6/2 is 3, and 13/3 rounds down to 4.

Comment: Note that you didn't get a list where each element was summed with `0` in the first example.

Comment: Kind-of similar, with `(/)` instead of `div`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611896/foldr-and-foldr1-haskell

Answer (score 6):

`foldr` looks like this:

```
foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 `f` (x2 `f` ... (xn `f` z)...)
```

So in your case:

```
foldr div 7 [13, 6, 19] == 13 `div` (6 `div` (19 `div` 7))
```

You can look stuff like this up on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle)! If you want a list with all numbers divided by 7, use [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map).